# Pagination in Handlebars superset dashboard

Tags: apache-superset

I am building a summary report and am choosing Handlebars chart type. Under the customize tab, I am preparing the Handlebars template with html code. It is showing the results as per the design. But I am not able to achieve the pagination. How to achieve the pagination in case of Handlebars chart?

```
<ul class="data-list">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>FilerID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  {{#each data}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{FilerID}}</td>
    <td><a href="/superset/dashboard/11/?Name={{Name}}">{{Name}}</a></td>
    <td>{{City}}</td>
    <td>{{Type}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
  </table>
</ul>
```

Not sure how to achieve it.